# Angular 5 and OpenLayers 4 : Cannot read property 'getEventPixel' and 'forEachFeatureAtPixel'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers

I'm trying to use OpenLayers with Angular 5.
I'm testing different ways to implement maps, I've already tested Leaflet and OpenLayers in simple HTML files and I've choosed to use OpenLayers which is more efficient in my case.

With this map I want to switch between different layers (with ol-layerswitcher), place markers according to a GeoJSON file and display popups.
All these features are well working in my HTML file and now, I want to do the same thing with Angular 5 (not with angular-openlayers-directive) !

I have adapted my HTML code in Angular in my app.component.ts file, the markers are displayed according to my GeoJSON file, my layer-switcher too but I have problems with two functions : forEachFeatureatPixel and getEventPixel ...

Here is my src/app/app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import OlMap from 'ol/map';
import OlWMS from 'ol/source/tilewms';
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OlView from 'ol/view';
import olProj from 'ol/proj';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/vector';
import Point from 'ol/geom/point';
import Style from 'ol/style/style';
import IconStyle from 'ol/style/icon';
import WFS from 'ol/format/wfs';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/geojson';
import Overlay from 'ol/overlay';
import feature from 'ol/feature';
import OlSwitch from 'ol-layerswitcher/src/ol-layerswitcher';
import CanvasMap from 'ol/canvasmap';
//import evt from 'ol/mapbrowserevent';
//import mbe from 'ol/mapbrowsereventtype';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  map: OlMap;
  gny_bright: OlWMS;
  gny_bright_mobile: OlWMS;
  layer: OlTileLayer;
  view: OlView;
  layerSwitcher: OlSwitch;
  WFS: WFS;
  vectorLayer: VectorLayer;
  sourceLayer: VectorSource;
  feature: feature;
  evt: evt;
  mbe: mbe;
  //parkvert: IconStyle;
  //parkorange: Style;
  //parkrouge: Style;
  //parknoir: Style;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.gny_bright = new OlWMS({
      url: '...',
      params: {...},
      attributions: '...'
    });

    this.gny_bright_mobile = new OlWMS({
      url: '...',
      params: {...},
      attributions: '...'
    });

    var parkvert = new Style({
      image: new IconStyle(({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'assets/image/parking-vert.png'
      }))
    });

    var parkorange = new Style({
      image: new IconStyle(({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'assets/image/parking-orange.png'
      }))
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
      center: [689805.19, 6222389.4],
      minZoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 19,
      zoom: 2
    });

    this.sourceLayer = new VectorSource({
      url: 'url_to_my_geojson_file',
      format: new GeoJSON()
    });

    this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.sourceLayer
    });

    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new OlTileLayer({
          title: 'gny_bright_mobile',
          source: this.gny_bright_mobile,
          type: 'base',
          attributions: '...'
        }),
        new OlTileLayer({
          title: 'gny_bright',
          source: this.gny_bright,
          type: 'base',
          attributions: '...'
        })
      ],
      view: this.view
    });

    var markers = function style(feature, resolution) {
      if (feature.get('PLACES') == null) {
        return parknoir;

      } else if(feature.get('PLACES') <= feature.get('CAPACITE') * 0.05) {
        return parkrouge;

      } else if(feature.get('PLACES') <= feature.get('CAPACITE') * 0.15){
        return parkorange;

      } else if(feature.get('PLACES') > feature.get('CAPACITE') * 0.15) {
        return parkvert;
      }
    }

    this.vectorLayer.setStyle(markers);

    //popup

    var element = document.getElementById('popup');

    var popup = new Overlay({
      element: element,
      autoPan: true,
      offset: [0, -30]
    });

  this.map.addOverlay(popup);

  var content_element = document.getElementById('popup-content');
  var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

  closer.onclick = function() {
        popup.setPosition(undefined);
        closer.blur();
        return false;
    };

    this.map.on('click', function(evt){
        this.feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
          function(feature) {
            return this.feature;
          });
          if (this.feature) {
            var geometry = this.feature.getGeometry();
            var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

            if(this.feature.get('NOM')!=null) {
              var content = '<center><h2>' + this.feature.get('NOM') + '</h2></center>' + '<br>';
            }

            if(this.feature.get('ADRESSE')!=null) {
              content += '<h5>' + '<i>Adresse : </i>' + this.feature.get('ADRESSE') + '</h5>';
            }

            if(this.feature.get('CAPACITE')!=null) {
              content += '<h5>' + '<i>Capacité : </i>' + this.feature.get('CAPACITE') + '</h5>';
            }

            if(this.feature.get('PLACES')!=null) {
              content += '<h5>' + '<i>Places disponibles : </i>' + this.feature.get('PLACES') + '<h5>';
            }

            content_element.innerHTML = content;
            popup.setPosition(coord);
        }
    });

    this.map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
        if (e.dragging) {
          return;
        };

        var pixel = this.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
        var hit = this.map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);

        this.map.getViewport().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
    });

    this.map.addControl(this.vectorLayer);
    this.layerSwitcher = new OlSwitch();
    this.map.addControl(this.layerSwitcher);
  }
}
```

My src/app/app.component.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
          <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
          <div id="popup-content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

My src/app/app.component.css :

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

My styles.css :

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
}

/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
.ol-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.ol-mouse-position {
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ol-scale-line {
  background: rgba(0,60,136,0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ol-scale-line-inner {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-top: none;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  will-change: contents, width;
}
.ol-overlay-container {
  will-change: left,right,top,bottom;
}

.ol-unsupported {
  display: none;
}
.ol-viewport, .ol-unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.ol-selectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: default;
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  -moz-user-select: auto;
  -ms-user-select: auto;
  user-select: auto;
}
.ol-grabbing {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
.ol-grab {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.ol-control {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ol-control:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.ol-zoom {
  top: .5em;
  left: .5em;
}
.ol-rotate {
  top: .5em;
  right: .5em;
  transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility 0s linear;
}
.ol-rotate.ol-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility 0s linear .25s;
}
.ol-zoom-extent {
  top: 4.643em;
  left: .5em;
}
.ol-full-screen {
  right: .5em;
  top: .5em;
}
@media print {
  .ol-control {
    display: none;
  }
}

.ol-control button {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.14em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.375em;
  width: 1.375em;
  line-height: .4em;
  background-color: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.ol-control button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.ol-zoom-extent button {
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.ol-compass {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  will-change: transform;
}
.ol-touch .ol-control button {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.ol-touch .ol-zoom-extent {
  top: 5.5em;
}
.ol-control button:hover,
.ol-control button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,60,136,0.7);
}
.ol-zoom .ol-zoom-in {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
.ol-zoom .ol-zoom-out {
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}


.ol-attribution {
  text-align: right;
  bottom: .5em;
  right: .5em;
  max-width: calc(100% - 1.3em);
}

.ol-attribution ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
.ol-attribution li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: inherit;
}
.ol-attribution li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
}
.ol-attribution img {
  max-height: 2em;
  max-width: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ol-attribution ul, .ol-attribution button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ol-attribution.ol-collapsed ul {
  display: none;
}
.ol-attribution.ol-logo-only ul {
  display: block;
}
.ol-attribution:not(.ol-collapsed) {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.ol-attribution.ol-uncollapsible {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0;
  height: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.ol-attribution.ol-logo-only {
  background: transparent;
  bottom: .4em;
  height: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.ol-attribution.ol-uncollapsible img {
  margin-top: -.2em;
  max-height: 1.6em;
}
.ol-attribution.ol-logo-only button,
.ol-attribution.ol-uncollapsible button {
  display: none;
}

.ol-zoomslider {
  top: 4.5em;
  left: .5em;
  height: 200px;
}
.ol-zoomslider button {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
}

.ol-touch .ol-zoomslider {
  top: 5.5em;
}

.ol-overviewmap {
  left: 0.5em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
}
.ol-overviewmap.ol-uncollapsible {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
}
.ol-overviewmap .ol-overviewmap-map,
.ol-overviewmap button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ol-overviewmap .ol-overviewmap-map {
  border: 1px solid #7b98bc;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 150px;
}
.ol-overviewmap:not(.ol-collapsed) button{
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ol-overviewmap.ol-collapsed .ol-overviewmap-map,
.ol-overviewmap.ol-uncollapsible button {
  display: none;
}
.ol-overviewmap:not(.ol-collapsed) {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.ol-overviewmap-box {
  border: 2px dotted rgba(0,60,136,0.7);
}

.ol-overviewmap .ol-overviewmap-box:hover {
  cursor: move;
}

.layer-switcher.shown.ol-control {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.layer-switcher.shown.ol-control:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.layer-switcher {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.5em;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

.layer-switcher.shown {
  bottom: 3em;
}

.layer-switcher .panel {
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 4px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.layer-switcher.shown .panel {
  display: block;
}

.layer-switcher button {
  float: right;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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') /*logo.png*/;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

.layer-switcher.shown button {
  display: none;
}

.layer-switcher button:focus, .layer-switcher button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.layer-switcher ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
  list-style: none;
}

.layer-switcher li.group {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.layer-switcher li.group > label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.layer-switcher li.layer {
  display: table;
}

.layer-switcher li.layer label, .layer-switcher li.layer input {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.layer-switcher label.disabled {
  opacity:0.4;
}

.layer-switcher input {
  margin: 6px;
}

.layer-switcher.touch ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

.layer-switcher.touch ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.layer-switcher.touch ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/** Popup */

.ol-popup {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 260px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: -50px;
}
.ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
  top: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.ol-popup:after {
  border-top-color: white;
  border-width: 10px;
  left: 48px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.ol-popup:before {
  border-top-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 11px;
  left: 48px;
  margin-left: -11px;
}
.ol-popup-closer {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 8px;
}
.ol-popup-closer:after {
  color: red;
  content: "✖";
}
```

All the code is working in Angular until the line '//popup' in scr/app/app.component.ts !

And after that line I have the two errors, getEventPixel when I fly over the map with my mouse and forEachFeatureAtPixel when I click on a marker ...

[Errors with forEachFeature at Pixel and getEventPixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEZMo.png)

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript is not Java. You did not bind the functions to your component, so `this` is not what you think it is. Read the [full article about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on mozilla.

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value.

But this is easily solved by using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)!

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

Consider your code below:

```
this.map.on('click', function(evt){ 
  this.map.getEventPixel
});
```

The code above tries to access a property map of the event function `function(evt)`, which it does not have. To fix it, just change it to an arrow function:

```
this.map.on('click', (evt) => { 
  this.map.getEventPixel
});
```

In the code above, `this` is actually the context of the component, so `map` is the property of the component.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried your solution and it's working fine.
I've also tried an another thing, I have deleted the line :

    map: OlMap;

and change :

    this.map = new OlMap({...
in :

    var map = new OlMap({...
I have deleted all "this.map" in "map" in the two functions that causing trouble in order to use the two functions (map.on('click') and map.on('pointermove')) like it was in my app.component.ts file (function(evt) and not (evt =>))

Is there a difference between the this and non-this method ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var map = ...` is a local variable, defined in the context of the component. It works because when accessing a variable "map" anywhere, it goes up the context stacks until it finds it. However, the downside is that you cannot access it from outside of it's context, which is possible when using `this.map`, which basically defines a property to the component (or to whatever the context is where you write `this.[...]`. It is admittedly an confusing topic in JS and worth getting some knowledge, it's a source for a lot of problems (and potential, I guess).

Comment: By the way, using a local variable like you successfully did was one of the solutions people tended to use before arrow-functions existed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for 'Cannot read property 'forEachFeatureAtPixel' of undefined' Error.

My Initial code (which will throw error):

```
this.map.on('click', function(evt){
   var feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
                    return feature;
                 });
   if (feature) {
      console.log("Feature found");
   }
});
```

Working code:

```
this.map.on('click', function(evt){
   var feature = evt.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
                    return feature;
                 });
   if (feature) {
     console.log("Feature found");
   }
});
```

Explanation:
Use map instance from click event (**evt**.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel) instead of root instance (**this**.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel).